# $.live() and $.die() binding and unbinding

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, live, die

I am having some trouble with jquery's live and die methods.

http://jsfiddle.net/fC5Nr/4/

```
//bind above function to clicking a
$('a').live('click', functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds)
```

I need to attach an event handler to clicking a link - and I want to unbind the handler while the function is running to prevent the function running over and over before it is complete (function is performing a ajax request then handling the response.

I can do all of the above just fine.

However, because the above handler is attached to  a (a) tag I need to return false (to prevent the link from being followed). To do this I need to bind a different function to handle clicks and return false.

I need to know how to unbind my complicated function - while keeping my simple (return false) bound at all times.

The above fiddle should work, but after unbinding the event handler, it doesn't bind again? I've tried a few combinations of namespacing etc but cannot get this together.

Comment: unbind and rebind? what's wrong with a simple flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** got it working

```
   function denyRest() {
        $("body").append("<h1>return false</h1>");
        return false;
    }
    function functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds() {
        $('a').die('click.thing', functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds);
        var loader = $('<div class="loader">doing some stuff</div>');
        $('#content').append(loader);
        loader.animate({
            'width': '500'
        }, 5000, function() {
            loader.remove();
            $('a').die('click.otherthing', denyRest).live('click.thing', functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds).live('click.otherthing', denyRest);
        });
    }

    $('a').live('click.thing', functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds);
    $('a').live('click.otherthing', denyRest);
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/fC5Nr/9/).

I *believe* The issue was this.

1. Use live to attach the handler to wait 5 seconds
2. Use live to attach a handler that returns false to stop events.
3. Click anchor tag, which removes the wait 5 second handler.
4. Clicks to the anchor tag at this time will be stopped via the return false statement.
5. **NOW** the return false statement is first.  Once we rebind the wait 5 seconds handler it is in second place to be ran but gets denied by the return false handler.
6. Fixed this to trash both handlers and rebind them in the correct order.

Comment: Awwwwwww Maaaaaaannnnn. I feel like such a fool right now. I was trying to namespace my events by putting a space between 'click namespace' instead of  a dot 'click.namepace'. thanks for posting this (bangs head off of desk)

Comment: In reply to your side note: the a tag is required to preserve functionality without javascript.

Comment: Sorry I spoke to soon. Your example does not work - it doesn't rebind the event handler after unbinding it (the same problem I was having...)

Comment: Ok, I *believe* it is working now, check out the updated fiddle and let me know.

Comment: @Mark - I believe this fails when you have multiple links. Clicking on one link and beginning the loader display will unbind the handler from all other links.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding I noticed that as well, however that is how the original markup is defined to `die` on all `<a/>` elements.  Hard to tell the true intent of a question when it is out of context.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the second attempt. It does seem like this makes a difference - but for the above list (1-6) to be true then the following fiddle would show the same issue. http://jsfiddle.net/67pWA/1/ . Because the first function returns false - it shouldn't stop the other functions from executing (and it doesn't) this seems to go aginst point 5 above.

Comment: edit: ignore that - It seems if you use live instead of bind http://jsfiddle.net/67pWA/2/ then it behaves exactly as you described. Any idea why these work in different ways? I might need to post an additional question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind this approach (using a marker class) then this might be what you're looking for. No messy binding and unbinding of events - while trying to figure out a way to answer you question, I found it to be quite a bother to track everything that was bound/unbound on the page and I reached a stage once where I had multiple loaders appear for a single click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds(el, e){
        //stop default link click events
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        if($(el).hasClass('loadingMarkerClass')) {
           return false; //we're currently processing this element already
       }
        $(el).addClass('loadingMarkerClass'); //add a dummy, marker class to indicate we're showing a loader for this element

        var loader = $('<div class="loader">Loading: ' + $(el).html() + '</div>');
        $('#content').append(loader);
        loader.animate({'width': '500'}, 5000, function(){
            loader.remove();
            $(el).removeClass('loadingMarkerClass');
        });
    }

    //bind above function to clicking a
    $('a').live('click', function(e){functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds(this, e)});

});
```

Comment: Oh? You can bind with 'live' and unbind with 'unbind' instead of die? Didn't know that :-) Thanks.

Comment: Also this would unbind the click event that i DONT want to unbind.

Comment: @calumbrodie I've updated my answer with something I think works - it handles multiple clicks on a link, allows for multiple links in the page and also prevents the links from being followed.

Comment: @calumbrodie I just signed up for jsfiddle and [updated the code](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/fC5Nr/10/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - your approach does work and the fiddle you've posted solves all the problems I pointed out. Still havn't got to the bottom of why my original code didn't work though

Comment: edit: I marked Marks answer as complete because he pointed out the flaw in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest way to achieve this will be to remove the href tag on the anchor link.

So your code becomes

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds(){
       // $('a').die('click', functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds);
        var loader = $('<div class="loader">doing some stuff</div>');
         $(this).attr("href","#");
            $('#content').append(loader)
            loader.animate({'width': '500'}, 5000, function(){
                loader.remove();
                //now rebind click handler
         //       $('a').live('click', functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds)
            })
    }



    //bind above function to clicking a
    $('a').live('click', functionThatWaitsFiveSeconds)

    //need to return false at all times to prevent folowing link
    $('a').live('click',function(){
        return false;    
    })
})
```

Comment: The <a> with the link is a requirement it is not optional. Thanks